# Workflow for patching and testing expl3 modules

Tags: expl3, debugging, workflow

Say I want to write a patch for one or some of the `expl3` modules. As far as I can see, to test the patch I have to do the following:

1. Edit the module's `.dtx` file;
2. Run `l3.ins` to compile (beside others) `expl3-code.tex` from *all* `l3kernel` modules;
3. Include package `expl3` from my main testing document.

For writing more complex patches that require you to repeatedly edit and test your code, this is tedious and impractical.

Ideally, I'd like to directly modify a `.dtx` file and include only that updated package into the main file. As `expl3` seems to include all packages, that won't work; including a separate package afterwards would cause errors because of duplicated definitions. (My first problem here is already how to properly create the `.sty` file from the `.dtx` file.)

So my questions:

1. Is there a way to selectively import `expl3` packages on top of the already loaded ones, or prepare a special version of `expl3` that will pull in the code from individual `.sty` files instead of one big kernel dump?
2. What is the workflow of active LaTeX3 developers? Do you have special building scripts or tools?
3. Are there other debugging options or tools (especially for the `expl3` packages) one should be aware of other that the few commands mentioned in `interface3.pdf`?

Comment: Just a stupid comment: if you are redefining an already existing macro from the kernel you can use the `gset` variant instead of `new`, then no verification whatsoever will be done and you can load your patch afterwards as a package. Then, after you're done, you can patch-in those changes to your copy of the sources and build it normally.

Comment: I run `l3build install` to install the files in a special texmf, for only l3kernel that's reasonable fast. But why are you changing the original dtx-files from expl3? Do you plan a pull request?

Comment: Yes, the point it to prepare patches that might actually go into the development version. So using `gset` is no alternative.

Answer (score 3):

Historically, we did load all of the `.sty` files separately, but the load order requirements made that tedious. Having each `.sty` separately was all a recipe for issues with mismatched versions. As such, we have moved to a single file. The reason is in part that `expl3` itself is quite stable, so the number of changes to it are normally limited.

For work on `expl3`, I use one of two workflows, depending on the detail. For simple changes, I just set up a test document which contains the code I want using `gset` rather than `new`. I test it 'locally', then copy back to the sources and make the adjustments needed. As it will need to pass the test suite anyway, that is normally fine.

The alternative, for bigger changes, is simply to alter the `.dtx` files and do an `install` to put it into my local tree, then again to run some 'local' tests. That is done using `l3build`. Once again, we need tests before adding new code, so there is always that to do.

Comment: Worth bearing in mind that the team also sort the format, where there really is no option but to install-and-build. So our workflow is based on having some non-trivial build set up most of the time.

Comment: I'm also not sure there is much difference between running DocStrip on a large set of files and running it just on one: it's quite a fast process.